# Use 24 pt font size in my poster with beamerposter

Tags: fontsize, beamerposter

I'm still new using beamerposter. I found the template by Nathaniel Johnston [here](http://www.njohnston.ca/2009/08/latex-poster-template/). There is a default setting in the template. However I'm not sure what the font size is. Now, I was recommended to use 24 pt font size by an advisor. The poster size is A0 if it is relevant. I looked around the web. One way to change the font size seems to be font size option in documentclass. I chose different font sizes, however it  doesn't reflect the change. The scale option does change the font size. However, it is hard to tell what the font size is.

```
\documentclass[final,24pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[size=a0,scale=1.0]{beamerposter}
\usetheme{confposter}

\begin{document}
This is current font size.
\end{document}
```

How can I use 24 pt size font in my poster? Otherwise how can I tell what font size is used so that I can adjust the font size by using scale option?

Comment: You can use the [`anyfontsize`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/anyfontsize) package, if I understand your request correct.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The template uses the documentclass `beamer`. Font sizes are predefined and there are eight default sizes:
8pt, 9pt, 10pt, 11pt, 12pt, 14pt, 17pt and 20pt.

If you want to achieve 24pt, then use 20pt as an option for the documentclass:

```
\documentclass[final,20pt]{beamer}
```

Set option `scale` from the `beamerposter`-package to scale from 20pt to 24pt (1.2*20 = 24):

```
\usepackage[size=a0,scale=1.2]{beamerposter}
```

The text in the poster is in normalsize by default, so you can be sure that the text will be 24pt.

Comment: It seems working according to your answer. By comparing the font size produced by the above setting to the font size produced by tikzposter which produces 25 pt font size, I can see the size is quite similar. The font size also seems to change to the predefined sizes. I wonder how beamerposter behaves if I choose the size not in the predefined sizes? It seems it picks up the one closest to the predefined size. But I'm not sure. Anyway, I believe it solved my problem.

Comment: If you don't choose a predefined size, it will pick the closest one (like you already discovered). A font size that is in between two font sizes (e.g. 13pt is between 12pt and 14pt) will be reduced to the smallest one (12pt).